# Counting values of other columns if applicable to assign value to new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, count, nan, nonetype

I have a dataframe something like this:

```
  A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
0 a    None 123  None Nan  None 2    aa,12asd
1 None 1234 456  None Ee5  tie  233  a,123,sd
2 None absc 789  Nan  Nan  abs  Abc  asd34vfd
```

I want to create a column 'I' which is essentially the count of columns A through H counting where applicable and ignoring where applicable. Output would be something like:

```
I
4
6
5
```

I have tried np.isnan, pd.isnull, .all(), .bool, .any, .empty, .item, .count- NONE are working.

Can anyone show how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we have the following DataFrame:

```
In [76]: df
Out[76]:
      A     B    C     D    E     F    G         H
0     a  None  123  None  Nan  None    2  aa,12asd
1  None  1234  456  None  Ee5   tie  233  a,123,sd
2  None  absc  789   Nan  Nan   abs  Abc  asd34vfd
```

where all `None` and `Nan` values are strings:

```
In [81]: df.isnull()
Out[81]:
       A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H
0  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

we can do the following:

```
In [77]: df['I'] = df.replace(['None','Nan'], [np.nan, np.nan]).notnull().sum(1)

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
      A     B    C     D    E     F    G         H  I
0     a  None  123  None  Nan  None    2  aa,12asd  4
1  None  1234  456  None  Ee5   tie  233  a,123,sd  6
2  None  absc  789   Nan  Nan   abs  Abc  asd34vfd  5
```

If you already have `None`'s and `NaN`'s (instead of strings):

```
In [87]: df.isnull()
Out[87]:
       A      B      C     D      E      F      G      H
0  False   True  False  True   True   True  False  False
1   True  False  False  True  False  False  False  False
2   True  False  False  True   True  False  False  False

In [88]: df['I'] = df.notnull().sum(1)

In [89]: df
Out[89]:
      A     B    C   D    E     F    G         H  I
0     a  None  123 NaN  NaN  None    2  aa,12asd  4
1  None  1234  456 NaN  Ee5   tie  233  a,123,sd  6
2  None  absc  789 NaN  NaN   abs  Abc  asd34vfd  5
```